# MS Publisher. How to create an A5 booklet folded on the long edge

Tags: microsoft-publisher

I want to create an A5 size booklet  (A4 paper folded), but the examples only allow for the fold to be on the short side of the paper  (portrait) and not on the long side of the paper  (Landscape).  Please assist!

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't folding along the short edge what happens when you place the page in Landscape (wide) and fold it across in front of you (a booklet), while the long edge is if you have the page in Portrait (tall) and fold it across (a flyer)?

Answer (score 3):

You can actually use "folding card" - I switched from "booklet" to "folding card" and it still printed out my full 12 page booklet with the fold on the top.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check out this guide MS provides: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-and-print-a-letter-sized-booklet-or-newsletter-c2f408d0-2f04-4d43-84ec-5b305b426aea

1. Set your paper orientation to Landscape.
2. Open the Page Layout dialog.
3. Set Layout Type to **Booklet**.
4. Confirm the dimensions and margin settings are correct.

Comment: Nope, this does not give me a Landscape A5 booklet with a fold on top (long edge)

Comment: It sounds as though you want to sent the paper in portrait and then apply all the elements to the document sideways.

Comment: I want a "top fold" for the booklet.  In Publisher is only gives me a "side fold".